# power bi embedded using no Azure sql server

Tags: azure, powerbi, powerbi-embedded, powerbi-datasource

Currently, I´m tryining to embedded power BI reports in our solution. To do that, I´m using power BI embedded. I have an Azure suscription and there I have created a workspace collection and many workspaces (one for any customer that uses my application). 
Foreach workspace I have updated the reports datasource in order to allow each customer to watch his own data.

Everything works correctly if the database is in Azure (SQL Azure), but the report shows an error when the database is not in Azure. 
This is the error: "Your data gateway (Power BI – personal) is offline, but a data gateway is available."

I know that it is possible to create a power bi gateway, but it works with a power bi account and I don´t want my customers to create an account. I want to offer power bi report as an integrated tool in my solution.

Many thanks.

Comment: At the moment, Power BI embedded does not support Data Gateway to on premises databases, if you use Power BI Embedded, you have to use Azure Database. In your case, you should use Power BI Service, you can create hidden Office 365 accounts programatically using Azure Graph API

Answer (score 0):

As Cuong Le mentioned this is not possible (yet). You could use a manual method of uploading a PBIX file with Imported data from any source, but this cannot be refreshed.

This is what is currently mentioned in the documentation:

> Supported data sources
>
> DirectQuery
>
> - Azure SQL database
> - Azure SQL Data Warehouse
>
> Import
>
> You can import using all of the available data sources within Power BI
> Desktop. **You will not be able to refresh that data within Power BI
> Embedded. You will have to upload changes to your PBIX file to Power
> BI Embedded. This is due to no available gateway.**

(https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/power-bi-embedded/power-bi-embedded-connect-datasource)

There is an Idea up for this which you could vote for. It seems Microsoft has already marked this Idea as "started", but there's no clear timeline for such a feature: https://ideas.powerbi.com/forums/265200-power-bi-ideas/suggestions/13439685-support-other-data-sources-direct-query-using-gate